# Excel copying to multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, input, copy

I have a master worksheet and several duplicates (basically they are all the same layout but different dates for each sheet)
I'm trying to allow the user to enter something on the master and then open an inputbox and allow the user to select multiple worksheets(tabs) and have that input copied to the selected tabs.

I can't seem to figure out which how to allow the user to select one or more tabs and then have the data from the master copy over to the same location in those tabs.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim tabs As Range

Sheets("MONTH").Select

Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select the cell(s) to copy", Type:=8)

Range(rng.Address).Select
Selection.Copy

Set tabs = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select the Tabs to copy", Type:=8)

For Each tabs In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
     MsgBox tabs.Name
Next tabs

'Sheets("d31").Activate
Worksheets(tabs).Select

Range(rng.Address).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Perhaps easier to give them a different way to select the sheets - using a listbox perhaps. Or just writing the names.

Comment: Or you could select the sheets before running the macro and store their names in an array. That's not ideal though as relies on a selection before the code is run.